# Improve car plate recognition

Tags: c++, opencv

I am working on school project which base on car plate recognition. I am testing it on simple movie: one car, static camera etc.

This how it looks like:

[image]

My first step was finding only car on this frame (I think it will be helpful for more "difficult" video):
[image]

Then I search car plate. Here is my code:

```
std::vector<cv::Rect> boundRect;
    cv::Mat img_gray, img_sobel, img_threshold, element;
    cvtColor(detectedMats[i], img_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    cv::Sobel(img_gray, img_sobel, CV_8U, 1, 0, 3, 1, 0, cv::BORDER_DEFAULT);
    cv::threshold(img_sobel, img_threshold, 0, 255, CV_THRESH_OTSU + CV_THRESH_BINARY);
    element = getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(30, 30));
    //element = getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(17, 3) ); 
    cv::morphologyEx(img_threshold, img_threshold, CV_MOP_CLOSE, element);
    std::vector< std::vector< cv::Point> > LP_contours;
    cv::findContours(img_threshold, LP_contours, 0, 1);
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours_poly(LP_contours.size());
    for (int ii = 0; ii < LP_contours.size(); ii++)
        if (LP_contours[ii].size() > 100 && contourArea(LP_contours[ii]) > 3000 && contourArea(LP_contours[ii]) < 10000) //można się pobawić parametrami
        {
            cv::approxPolyDP(cv::Mat(LP_contours[ii]), contours_poly[ii], 3, true);
            cv::Rect appRect(boundingRect(cv::Mat(contours_poly[ii])));


            if (appRect.width > appRect.height)
                boundRect.push_back(appRect);
        }
```

And result you can see at the second picture.

Then tried get good contours of detect plate. I did few steps.

1. Given the drastic changes in brightness, by histogram equalization:

[image]

2. Use filter and threshold:

   ```
       cv::Mat blur;
       cv::bilateralFilter(equalized, blur, 9, 75, 75);
       cv::imshow("Filter", blur);

       /* Threshold to binarize the image */

       cv::Mat thres;
       cv::adaptiveThreshold(blur, thres, 255, cv::ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv::THRESH_BINARY, 15, 2); //15, 2
       cv::imshow("Threshold", thres);
   ```

[image]

[image]

3. Finally I find contours but they aren't so good. Numbers are a little bit blurred:

   ```
       std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
       cv::findContours(thres, contours, cv::RETR_LIST, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
       //cv::findContours(thres, contours, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));

       double min_area = 50;
       double max_area = 2000;
       std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > good_contours;
       for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
       {
           double area = cv::contourArea(contours[i]);
           if (area > min_area && area < max_area)
               good_contours.push_back(contours[i]);
       }
   ```

   [image]

Maybe you have some idea how to improve result? I tried change some parameters but it still doesn't work so well.

Thanks for help

---------------------------EDIT: tesseract installation------------------------

1. I install vcpkg.
2. Use

   ```
     .\vcpkg install tesseract:x64-windows-static
   ```

   At the end of installation I get some errors:
      [image]
3. But when I check it seems fine:
   [image]
4. And after integrate install I get this:
   [image]
5. Add lib to project:
   [image]

So it seems fine but when I tried run example the VS doesn't see libraries:

[image]

**SOLVED:**

Change

```
.\vcpkg install tesseract:x64-windows-static
```

into

```
.\vcpkg install tesseract:x64-windows
```

and it works nice.

Comment: If this code works then this question is off-topic on Stack Overflow. You'll need a more general-purpose forum for this sort of [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Your image at step 2 is good enough for sending to tessaract for the text recognition.

Comment: @seccpur Can you tell a little more about tessaract for the text recognition, please? I have never used it before.

Comment: @begginer: Tessaract OCR is a open source text recognition software. You can send the image as input and the library will convert to string.

Comment: @seccpur Thank you. Do you have maybe some good tutorial how to connect it with VS17 on Win10 or some simple code which show some tips how to use it in my case?

Comment: @begginer: Using vcpkg (open source packaging tool ) will make the installation on VS2017 with Win10 super simple. The included beginner's tutorial should be good enough in your case.

Comment: @seccpur Can you help me a little? I installed vcpkg (I think correctly) then I used this two commands (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50662383/10134831). During tesseract install i got some errors but when I search it finds  tesseract         3.05.02 as well and I get "All MSBuild C++ projects can now #include any installed libraries.". What now? When I build new project, it doesn't find these libraries at all. Have you maybe some tips?

Comment: @begginer: `.\vcpkg install tessaract:x64-windows-static` and then , if you want auto linking use `.\vcpkg integrate install `, it should link automatically for you.

Comment: . After successful installation of tesseract, add tesseract305.lib and leptonica-1.74.4.lib in the additional dependencies.

Comment: Still doesn't work (look at edit part) but I don't want take your time :). If you have some suggestions then let me know. I will try solve it somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use tesseract OCR to detect the text. After successful installation of tesseract, add tesseract305.lib and leptonica-1.74.4.lib in the additional dependencies. Use the following code ( from tutorial) :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "winsock2.h"

#include <tesseract/baseapi.h>
#include <leptonica/allheaders.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

int main()
{
    char *outText;

    tesseract::TessBaseAPI *api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();

    // Initialize tesseract-ocr with English, without specifying tessdata path
    if (api->Init(NULL, "eng")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize tesseract.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Open input image with leptonica library
    Pix *image = pixRead("test.tif");
    api->SetImage(image);
    // Get OCR result
    outText = api->GetUTF8Text();
    printf("OCR output:\n%s", outText);

    // Destroy used object and release memory
    api->End();
    delete[] outText;
    pixDestroy(&image);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I did everything as you wrote and even I used the same example bo it doesn't work. If you have some time, can you look at edit part of my post? Maybe you see what is wrong :)

Comment: Tesseract is not suitable for Unicode languages (such as Arabic) because it is not giving accurate results