# Install Tesseract for C++ on Windows 7

Tags: c++, windows, installation, ocr, tesseract

I'm using C++ and compiling my project files directly from the Windows console using GCC. I want to install and to be able to use Tesseract on Windows 7. I tried following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66001590/14972751) step by step but got a *msvcp140.dll error* (not found) when trying to use *vcpkg.exe*

So there's something missing (I suppose I needed to download *something* that brings that runtime package within) (I also thought that downloading that single file mightn't meet all the future requirements) and I couldn't find a proper guide from the beginning to the end. Can someone please help me? After installing Tesseract properly, would it be enough for me to add its folders to my system path so that I'll be able to use it in g++.exe command line parameters just as I link another libraries?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation points to comment, but a quick google search says to try installing Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015. Not sure if you have already, but if not, it might be worth a try.

Solution: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance-winpc/msvcp140dll-is-missing-in-my-win-10/1c65d6b0-68b8-4b59-b720-3e6a33038389
Download: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145

Comment: Even after reinstalling it, the error persists. I can see that `msvcp140.dll` under `\System32` folder, still it says missing.

Comment: I tried copying that file to `\vcpkg` folder, this time it says _application could not start correctly._

Comment: Try installing both x86 and x64 versions of the redistributable (apparently this was the solution for several people), if that doesn't work, try adding the dll to system path. That's all the ideas I have.